# PHPMailer Content-Transfer-Encoding

Tags: php, phpmailer

If I send any mails with Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit those mails will actually be sent with Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted Printable!

I can't find any solution for this, and it's getting frustating.

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding - 8bit*m*` Is this typo just in the question, or also in your code?

Comment: ahh, sorry, was just a typo, it's "8bit"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My phpmailer installation uses 8bit by default. No need to change anything.

However if I want "quoted printable", I just add the following code:

```
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
```

One thing to remember: When you want quoted-printable you do not need to pre-encode your text, Phpmailer will encode it for you.

Maybe you can try without defining the encoding and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `8bitm` is not supported, so PHPMailer falls back to qp? I'm not sure off the top of my head, but shouldn't it be `8-bit` or `8bit` ?

Comment: no, it is 8bit.
the thing is that 7bit works, base64 works. everything works, except 8bit.

Comment: If "it is 8bit", @MihaiIorga, why does the question say *8bitm*?

Comment: @TRiG When I originally posted the question I didn't had enough reputation to edit it. Modified now :)